# Seprarate /home vs speratate /home + storage partition

Tags: partitioning, multi-boot

I am basically trying a clean install on my laptop to dual boot mint and arch. I want to have some  shared storage space for them but separate roots and also get to keep my dot config files from my homes. If I used the classic shared /home strategy there would be username conflicts and other things too consider.

So this is what I came up with:

```
/swap (2 gigs)
arch root(10 gigs)
arch home(5 gigs)
mint root(10 gigs)
mint home(5 gigs)
/mnt/storage(everything else)
```

This design allows me to keep my configs in case of a clean install and also provide that storage partition to which folders such as "Downloads" and "Videos" link to via symbolic links. My question is: what drawbacks can it have, and if I were to use the standard separate /home setup where would I locate my storage directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The down side is that you might run out of space on one of the partitions or later need to add/remove/resize partitions, and that can become a pain.  You might want to use LVM to manage the volumes instead, and leave some unassigned space so you can easily create more or expand the existing volumes later if needed.

Comment: I think 15 Gbs total(home + root) is enough to accommodate most distros,andnot to run into any problems I will use a LVM from the start. After all how long can moving 10gbs partitions take on a LVM? Thanks for the reassurance anyway. :D

Comment: @nikita.utiu, the beauty of LVM is that you don't have to move partitions to extend them; they can grow into any free space wherever it is ( even on other disks ).  Also if you do need to move ( maybe to migrate to a new disk ) you can so safely on the fly, while it is still mounted.

Comment: I might also try spearate home with a shared folder owned by a group.